# Web deploy task failed: data loss might occur when deploying to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I have MVC project which uses EF code first and I'm trying to publish to azure from Visual Studio but I'm receiving error: "Web deploy task failed: data loss might occur". I did some refactoring including renaming columns and I'm aware why the error occurs but I would like to force the migration because I'm sure that I handled the data loss:-) Nevertheless I have no idea how to skip data loss check. I've found that on SQL project you have option in properties that you can uncheck the 'block potential data loose' but I cannot find anything like that on my MVC project. I've tried to include my own script for schema update without the checks for data loss but EF complains that there are pending migrations, so I've tried to copy missing entries to _MigrationHistory table from my development db but it turned out that it's not that simple ;-) Because my app is still in development phase I have reinitialized db but It will be worth to know how to handle that kind of situation on "real" production environment:-)

Edit: 
After some testing I've discovered that when publishing to azure there is now option "update database" which by default generates db update script based on diff on the local and azure db. It differs from the old "Run Code First migration" because the the old one was changing Db initializer to `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` and on application start the db was migrated & seed was run when there were not applied migrations. The "update database" process in other hand  is handled only by generated script and the migrations files and MigrationsHistory table is not used on production, neither the seed method. I was confused on the beginning but now it seems logical that update script gives more control over the database change, you always can modify the script, and furthermore the publish process of moving new code to azure performs only after successful db update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is an option called AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed, set this to true.  And run Update-Database -Force.  That should do it.

Comment: I have tried the `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed`  but I was relied on `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer which does not take that flag into consideration(in my tests). Think that migrating from package manager console with -Force will do the trick. I have nothing to test on now and I have already changed update scenario to "update database" script (more info in edit) but I think that this answer can be accepted :-)